# Android Studio Java JDK environment path

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I launch an Android Studio software I saw the dialog box below showing

> Error launching android studio The environment variable JAVA_HOME(with
>   the value of C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin) does not
>   point to a valid JVM installation

My JDK is placed on the location mentioned above, why Android Studio software still can't detect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up an Environment Var (Systemsettings->system->extended Settings->Environment Vars) which is called JAVA_HOME and point to your jdk folder, not your bin folder.

Example Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\

Comment: np. Do not forget to vote up if it helped you. cheers, Emanuel